# ActiveRecord scope cache for remote attribute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, scope, rails-activerecord

I have a large project, there are several separated db instance, database name and different table names, all need to be processed in single one Sinatra controller.

Something like this

```
class ItemLog < ActiveRecord::Base
  def address
    http_get('http://x.com/get_address_by_item_type?id=' + self.type_id).to_json['address']
  end
end
```

so if I iterated through a long list of ItemLog, the http get called multiple times **per each ItemLog**.

But since `ItemLog.type_id` is a limited set, but it's saved in a remote db, It's ideal that for each unique `type_id`, we only need to issue exactly one http request.

I know how to declare a standalone hash for caching like this:

```
address_cache = Hash[ItemLog.where(...).limit(500).pluck(:type_id).uniq.map {|type_id| [type_id, get_address(type_id)] }]
ItemLog.where(...).limit(500).each { |item| item.address = address_cache[item.type_id }
```

My question is is there anyway to write more elegant code for this? Something like "scope cache" works like a {item_type_id: address_string} pairs, but directly in a encapsulated   ActiveRecord model

Comment: Why not save the address in your database? Like in a `before_create` block ?

Comment: @avlazarov obviously because the remote db is not in my control. And its data gets updated very often, without any possible triggering mechanism. So fresh fetching everytime is essential